# Cannot deserealize Json string (C#)

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have JSON string that came from AWS Lambda:

```
   "body": "{'From': nemesises@live.com, 'To': suhomlin.eugene93@gmail.com}",
```

And try to deserialize it like this

```
 var email = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendEmailMessage>(emailRequest.Message);
```

Here is the class to what I need to deserialize

```
 public class SendEmailMessage
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    
    public string To { get; set; }
    
    public object Data { get; set; }
    
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    
    public List<string> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

But I get this error

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected content while parsing JSON. Path 'From', line 1, position 11.

How I can solve this?

Comment: Json structure is either encapsulated in `{}` for object or `[]` for an array. Here we have no  `{}` . The structure also doesn't match. The property `body` match no property of the object. I recommend using automatted class generation like [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) . A simple copy past and the class is generated.

Comment: You also have a weird js object inside the `body` proeprty `{'From': nemesises@live.com, 'To': suhomlin.eugene93@gmail.com}`. With single quote property name and unquoted value. Are you trying to deserialize that part? Because unquoted value are going to be a night mare. Email address allows `,;:` in quoted string And comment can be quoted(single). leaving you with an unquoted un escaped value that will not be quotable by anymean.

Comment: I need to leave it quoted by a single quote because it's the only way as I know to send JSON in AWS Lambda body @Self

Comment: My comment is about unquoted value. single quote are not an issue. If you single quote propertly like `{'From': 'nemesises@live.com', 'To': 'suhomlin.eugene93@gmail.com'}`. It works. https://dotnetfiddle.net/5bMeGW

Comment: "I need to leave it quoted by a single quote because it's the only way as I know to send JSON in AWS Lambda body" - but that's not valid JSON. It's entirely possible to represent valid JSON as the string value for a JSON property - you just need to perform appropriate escaping, which I'd expect any decent JSON library to do for you.

Comment: The correct way is to have a proper serialization `"body": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}",` with proper escaping.

Comment: @Self: While it happens to work with Json.NET, I'd still strongly discourage the use of single-quoted JSON which isn't actually valid JSON. I wouldn't be surprised if System.Text.Json fails on the same data, for example. Better to use valid JSON right from the start, IMO.

Comment: Without proper serialization and escaping a simple valid email address like `very.” , notAProperty : NotAValue , ”.VERY.”very@\\ "very”.unusual@example.com` will break any parser.

Comment: Already solve problem and wrote an answer @Self

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the entire json in {}.

```
{
"body": "{'From': nemesises@live.com, 'To': suhomlin.eugene93@gmail.com}"
}
```

You can use a site like https://jsonlint.com/ to work out things like this.

Comment: That's a starting point... but the value of the `body` property is presumably expected to be valid JSON, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the format of the body

Here the correct format is

```
{
    "Records": [
      {
        "messageId": "19dd0b57-b21e-4ac1-bd88-01bbb068cb78",
        "receiptHandle": "MessageReceiptHandle",
        "body": "{ \"Message\":\"{ 'from': 'nemesises@live.com','to': 'suhomlin.eugene93@gmail.com',}\"}",
        "attributes": {
          "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
          "SentTimestamp": "1523232000000",
          "SenderId": "123456789012",
          "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1523232000001"
        },
        "messageAttributes": {},
        "md5OfBody": "7b270e59b47ff90a553787216d55d91d",
        "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
        "eventSourceARN": "arn:{partition}:sqs:{region}:123456789012:MyQueue",
        "awsRegion": "{region}"
      }
    ]
  }
```